How to recover from Error processing request (java.nio.BufferUnderflowException) after input of nt file?
After many successful imports of mixed RDF triple formats (ttl, nt, etc), the import chokes on one by getting into what seems like a very long (maybe infinite) loop.
When trying to connect to the triplestore instance, I see the following message:
"Error processing request (java.nio.BufferUnderflowException)."
Is there a way to recover the data?

Do you have the output from the error log file? Is there significant reasoning happening? How big is the file that hangs? Have you reproduced this? How are you connecting to the database?

You can write to graphdb-support@ontotext.com.
